# When trying to fetch Google Calendars in iOS, console shows weird api#channel conflicts. How to solve?

Tags: ios, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to build an app that will fetch Google Calendar information such as calendars, events etc but I am running into a big problem.

This is my code:

```
#define GoogleClientID    @"client id"
#define GoogleClientSecret @"secret"
#define GoogleAuthURL   @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
#define GoogleTokenURL  @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"Calendar Panel: Google Calendar";

- (instancetype)initWithViewController: (UIViewController*) viewController;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _viewController = viewController;

    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isSignedIn {
    NSString *name = [self signedInUsername];
    return (name != nil);
}

- (NSString *)signedInUsername {
    // Get the email address of the signed-in user
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = self.calendarService.authorizer;
    BOOL isSignedIn = auth.canAuthorize;
    if (isSignedIn) {
        return auth.userEmail;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * )authForGoogle
{
    //This URL is defined by the individual 3rd party APIs, be sure to read their documentation

    NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:GoogleTokenURL];
    // We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
    // the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
    // loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page. This needs to match the URI set as the
    // redirect URI when configuring the app with Instagram.
    NSString * redirectURI = @"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"lifebeat"
                                                             tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                          redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                             clientID:GoogleClientID
                                                         clientSecret:GoogleClientSecret];
    auth.scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    return auth;
}


- (void)signInToGoogle
{
    if (![self isSignedIn]) {

        GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [self authForGoogle];


        // Display the authentication view
        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                                                    authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GoogleAuthURL]
                                                                                                    keychainItemName:@"GoogleKeychainName"
                                                                                                            delegate:self
                                                                                                    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
        [[self.viewController navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    } else
        NSLog(@"Something wrong with the sign in procedure!");
}


- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth
                 error:(NSError * )error
{
    NSLog(@"finished");
    NSLog(@"auth access token: %@", auth.accessToken);
    self.calendarService.authorizer = auth;

    [[self.viewController navigationController] popToViewController:self.viewController animated:NO];
    if (error != nil) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Google"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success Authorizing with Google"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)fetchCalendarList {
    self.calendarList = nil;
    self.calendarListFetchError = nil;

    GTLServiceCalendar *service = self.calendarService;


    GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForCalendarListList];

    self.calendarListTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                      id calendarList, NSError *error) {
                                      // Callback
                                      self.calendarList = calendarList;
                                      self.calendarListFetchError = error;
                                      self.calendarListTicket = nil;

                                      NSLog(@"Fetched number of calendars: %@", self.calendarList);
                                      //[self updateUI];
                                  }];

    //[self updateUI];
}

- (GTLServiceCalendar *)calendarService {
    static GTLServiceCalendar *service = nil;

    if (!service) {
        service = [[GTLServiceCalendar alloc] init];

        // Have the service object set tickets to fetch consecutive pages
        // of the feed so we do not need to manually fetch them
        service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;

        // Have the service object set tickets to retry temporary error conditions
        // automatically
        service.retryEnabled = YES;
    }
    return service;
}

@end
```

This is console output:

```
2014-09-10 23:57:53.603 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLDriveChannel (api#channel) registration conflicts with GTLCalendarChannel
2014-09-10 23:57:53.607 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusDomainsAcl (plus#acl) registration conflicts with GTLPlusAcl
2014-09-10 23:57:53.607 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusDomainsActivity (plus#activity) registration conflicts with GTLPlusActivity
2014-09-10 23:57:53.608 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusDomainsActivityFeed (plus#activityFeed) registration conflicts with GTLPlusActivityFeed
2014-09-10 23:57:53.608 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusDomainsComment (plus#comment) registration conflicts with GTLPlusComment
2014-09-10 23:57:53.609 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusDomainsCommentFeed (plus#commentFeed) registration conflicts with GTLPlusCommentFeed
2014-09-10 23:57:53.609 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusPeopleFeed (plus#peopleFeed) registration conflicts with GTLPlusDomainsPeopleFeed
2014-09-10 23:57:53.610 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusPerson (plus#person) registration conflicts with GTLPlusDomainsPerson
2014-09-10 23:57:53.610 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLPlusPlace (plus#place) registration conflicts with GTLPlusDomainsPlace
2014-09-10 23:57:53.613 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] GTLStorageChannel (api#channel) registration conflicts with GTLDriveChannel
2014-09-10 23:57:53.986 CalendarPanel[24383:60b] Fetched number of calendars: (null)
```

My two questions is:
 1. How can I get rid of these conflicts?
 2. Does my code look ok for what I want to do? (fetch all calendars from the user) I think using this GData classes is really tricky and there is very limited/or very outdated information out there.

Comment: Are you also using those other APIs in your app? (Drive, Plus, etc)

Comment: No, not intentionally at least. I only want to use Calendar API

Comment: Which library version are you using, and how did you go about installing it?

Comment: I have the exact console warnings in the app I'm working on. Library is installed via Cocoapod: pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 0.1'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of installing the entire Pod try use subpods

```
pod 'Google-API-Client/Calendar', '~> 1.0'
```

or whichever you need

```
pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive', '~> 1.0'
```